# How to change drawableEnd property of TextView

Tags: android, kotlin

> I have a Textview which I set the property drawableRight from my xml file, now I will like to change the drawable programatically.
>   I want when clicked, drawable icon/image should change from let say btn_up to btn_down.

Below is what I tried so far:

> **Class:**

```
requireText.SetOnClickListener {

requireText.drawableRight = resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_up)

}
```

> **xml:**

```
<TextView
  android:id="@+id/requireText"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
  android:background="@null"
  android:clickable="true"
  android:drawableRight="@drawable/btn_down"/>
```

How do I solve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There is no *`.drawableRight`* or Left, not yet for now, you can try below code:

```
   class SampleActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    var up = true
    var drawable: Drawable ?=null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup)

        userName.setOnClickListener {
            if(up){
                up = false
                drawable = resources.getDrawable(com.exolve.eros.R.drawable.sampleDownDrawable)
            }else{
                up = true
                drawable = resources.getDrawable(com.exolve.eros.R.drawable.sampleUpDrawable)
            }

            drawable!!.setBounds(0, 0, 10, 10)
            userName.setCompoundDrawables(drawable, null, null, null)
        }
    }
}
```

> An update to the fact that you want to switch the drawable on click.

Comment: Thanks for u r answer. !! It can use well.

Comment: Good to know, take note that writing if statements like @Xuzan wrote is not wrong but a bad practice and your code will mostly not be easily readable, Xuzan, pls note that simplicity is the best way to go when writing code, I learnt that the hard way.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var isClicked = false // declare this at top               
requireText.setOnClickListener{

   requireText.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, 
   if(!isClicked) R.drawable.btn_up else R.drawable.btn_down, 0)
   isClicked = !isClicked
 }
```

Comment: But when I click Textview again, I want btn up change btn down . How can I do it ??

Answer (score 0):

try this code to set drawable right in kotlin class

```
 val my_text_view = findViewById(R.id.my_text_view)
        my_text_view.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener { my_text_view.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.ic_arrow_upward_black_24dp, 0) })
```